# sql: How can I count(*) same values and put an additional flag to each row?

Tags: sql

I have the following table

[image]

and I want to select all rows with an additional field membership, if the 'projectid' is '1' (given by parameter in JPA). That's my result.

How can I add a second additional field with the number of same values of 'userid'?

[image]

The final result should be like (table final result):

[image]

and in 'numberOfMembership' I need number of how often the 'userid' is in the column userid.

[image]

In other words, how can I combine the following table with table 'final result'

[image]

respectively the two statements

```
SELECT userid, COUNT(userid) AS numberOfMembership 

FROM app_user_project 

GROUP BY userid
```

and

```
SELECT userid, projectid, (select '') AS numberOfmemberships, 
       if (projectid = '1', 'isMember', 'false') AS membership

FROM app_user_project GROUP BY userid, projectid 

ORDER BY membership
```

The problem I have is in the different count of rows in the two tables. Thank you!

To create the simple data set in a table:

> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `app_user_project` (
> `userid` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
> `projectid` bigint(20) NOT NULL
> ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

> INSERT INTO `app_user_project` (`userid`, `projectid`) VALUES
> (1, 1),
> (2, 1),
> (3, 1),
> (4, 1),
> (5, 1),
> (6, 1),
> (1, 2),
> (2, 2),
> (3, 2),
> (4, 2);

Comment: Can you add your simple data as code instead of images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query 1:

```
select userid,projectid, case when projectid = 1 then 'isMember' when projectid = 2 then 'false' end as membership from SOQ2 order by membership;
```

[image]

Query 2:

```
select userid,projectid, count(userid) over(partition by userid) as 'numberOfmembership',case when projectid = 1 then 'isMember' when projectid = 2 then 'false' end as membership from SOQ2 order by membership;
```

[image]

Query 3:

```
select distinct userid, count(userid) over(partition by userid) as 'numberOfmembership' from SOQ2;
```

[image]

Comment: Change your table name